# Find missing library or reference in vb6.0

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

Is there any way to find out which project library or reference is missing? or to get more detail about the missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it under project > Reference menu

Also check Project-Components which lists controls (OCX files) that are also references.

Answer (score -1):

yes u can see them.. u can find in one of the menus with the name **References**. i dont exactly remember the menu name under which u can find it. but u can see what all references are actually active for your project in that tab.